# retornar array de objetos php

Tags: php, object

Hola tengo una funcion en php que me devuelve un array de objetos pero al hacer un var_dump me muestra esto:

```
object(ArrayObject)#8 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(0) { } } 

 $conductor=new Conductor($fila['dni'],
                                             $fila['nombre'],
                                             $fila['telefono'],
                                             $fila['capMercancias'],
                                             $fila['fechaMercancias'],
                                             $fila['capViajeros'],
                                             $fila['fechaViajeros'],
                                             $fila['adr'],
                                             $fila['fechaAdr'],
                                             $fila['tacografo'],
                                             $fila['fechaTacografo'],
                                             $fila['token'],
                                             $fila['notificado'],
                                             $fila['avisado']
                                             );
                                    $conductor->setNotificado($valor);
                                    $usuariosNotificados->append($conductor
```

$usuariosNotificados es el array

Comment: si disculpa no me di cuenta

Comment: caul es el error? si te muestra eso es que el array no esta vacio

Comment: no es un error, pero no se como sacar los datos del array lo he intentando con un for pero nada

Comment: Por favor edita y mejora la pregunta, indicas que tienes una función/método que que retorna un array y te da problemas, añadela para que podamos revisarla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Igual puedes intentar esto con foreach:

```
foreach ($usuariosNotificados as $usuarios) {
  echo $usuarios->id . " " . $usuarios->valor; }
```

Comment: Creo que en vez de id debería ser dni. Espero te sirva.

Comment: gracias ya me funciono

Answer (score 0):

no te imprime haci en tu vista?

```
echo $conductor['nombre'];
```

para imprimir en una  tabla si es unan lista de columnas

```
<?php


foreach($perfiles as $perfil){
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $perfil['experiencia'] ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
```

Comment: gracias por su ayuda ya me funcionoo